# Ring of polynomials $\mathbb{Z}/(n)[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm doing problems in Artin on rings, and in problem 11.2.1, he asks:

> For which positive integers *n* does the polynomial $x^2+x+1$ divide $x^4+3x^3+x^2+7x+5$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/(n)[x]$?

Using basic long division, I found that the remainder was $7x+7$, and as we need $r(x)=0$ in order for divisibility, I assume we need a ring such that $7$ is equivalent to zero (additive identity?)
The issue is that our professor didn't really go over polynomial rings aside from the basic definitions, so I'm still not clear about this point.

However, my ultimate question is that, given that $(n)$ is the ideal generated by $n$, what are the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/(n)[x]$? I'm having a hard time seeing what the coefficients are supposed to be.

Comment: Welcome! I've edited your post to include MathJax, which you can learn more about from [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You can also click "edit" below your post to see what I changed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation looks good to me. By the division algorithm,
$$x^4 + 3 x^3 + 7 x + 5 
= (x^2 + 2 x - 2 ) ( x^2 + x + 1) + 7x + 7,$$
so we will have divisibility when $7x+7=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(n)[x]$. 
So go to the definition. Polynomials are equal when their coefficients are equal. So we must have $7=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$, which holds if and only if $n=7$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My main issue is that I didn't understand what Z/(n) was, but as you and Igor both pointed out, it's just the ring of Z mod n.

Comment: Technically each element of $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ is an entire equivalence class under arithmetic mod $n$, so one such element is $\{\dots, -2n+1, -n+1, 1, n+1, 2n+1, 3n+1, \dots \}$ but by abuse of notation people usually would write that using the representative element 1. Writing things this way means we can write $a=b$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ instead of $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an ideal is just a ring, so whatever you know about polynomial rings over rings applies, and your answer is correct. As for latex, see http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex

Comment: Yes, it's a ring, but I'm still lost as to how we're supposed to find n such that the coefficients are zero.  As far as my understanding goes, \mathbb{Z}/(n)[x] is a ring of cosets.

Thanks for the link by the way.

Comment: I think your professor just meant that use modular arithmetic, which is what you did.

Comment: So, is this ring equivalent to Z mod n then?  In that case, n=7 would certainly work.

Comment: Yes, exactly....

Comment: I get why now.  Thanks for the help!